# solving recurrence relations for functions with more than one variable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Is there a way to find formula for a function on more than one variable which is given by recurrence relation with some initial conditions?
e.g.if one knows the value of f(n,p,l) for all p,l where n,p,l are positive integers.The recurrence for f(n+1,p,l) is given by following:f(n+1,p,l) = f(n,p+1,l-1)+(1-x)f(n-1,p,l+1).how to find a formula for f(n,p,l)?

Comment: like $a_{j,k} = b a_{j-1, k-1}+c$ for example?

Comment: You need to be more specific. For some types of recurrences there are methods, but the general answer is 'no'.

Comment: In general, you want to use [generating functions] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), whether or not you will end up with something 'simple' or even 'solvable' heavily depends on the recurrence relation itself.